# Mongoose node js $match not working on array of objectIds?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

Hi i want to match in an array of objectIds in mongoose using node js but i got the result in mongo shell but when implement with my code not find any result.

This is my collection.

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("59c21ef1a870b05034f2cec1"),
"__v" : 0,
"name" : "Force",
"createdAt" : ISODate("2017-09-20T07:55:29.816Z"),
"updatedAt" : ISODate("2017-09-20T07:55:29.817Z"),
"createdBy" : "599bfa0ee67842000493fefc",
"timestamp" : 1505894129819.0,
"isDeleted" : 0,
"isActive" : 1,
"updatedBy" : "",
"subSegments" : [ 
    ObjectId("59c2172ab500ce0a946aa93a"), 
    ObjectId("59c21734b500ce0a946aa93b")
],
"segments" : [ 
    ObjectId("59c2166db500ce0a946aa935"), 
    ObjectId("59c216a5b500ce0a946aa936")
],
"subject" : [ 
    ObjectId("59c2179fb500ce0a946aa93f")
]
```

}

This is my query :-

```
 Topic.aggregate([
            {
                $unwind: "$subject"
            },
            {
                $match:{subject: new Mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId("59c2179fb500ce0a946aa93f")}
             }                
        ]
```

When i am running this query on mongo shell got result but in my code this query not return any result or error .

Answer (score 0):

If you are using mongoose, you can just say this,

```
Topic.find({
  subject: $in: ["59c2179fb500ce0a946aa93f"]
})
```